# What is the difference between intercept-resend attack and measure-resend attack?

Tags: cryptography, quantum-operation

I am going through different types of attacks that eve can perform on the quantum channel. I came across the intercept-resend attack and measure-resend attack. What is the difference between the two?

According to my view,

1. measurement attack - Eve measures the particles going from Alice to Bob as in BB84 protocol
2. intercept-resend - Eve can apply a unitary operation

Am I correct?